# How break out of an external loop from its nested loop in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

How break out of an external loop from its nested loop in Solidity? E.g. is there anything like that:

```
if (uint8 i; i < 10; i++) {
    if (uint8 j; j < 10; j++) {
        break 2; // construction that appears in several languages as PHP
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simulate this by creating a temporary variable,  or you can put the loops in a function and use a return instead

**Note:** Your syntax should be using for loops not ifs

```
bool breakOuterLoop = false;
for(uint8 i; i < 10; i++) {
    for (uint8 j; j < 10; j++) {
        if(myCondition) {
            breakOuterLoop = true;
            break; 
        }
    }
    if(breakOuterLoop) {
        break;
    }
}
```

**Note:** MyCondition is represent the condition you want to break on (since it wasn't included in your original example)